# How do we check the Roles from Router-React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I want to add Roles to the router.

I have written protected router I want to pass a prop allowedRole to protectedRouter.

AllowedRoles are array of objects

App.js

```
function App() {
// Initialize state from localStorage
const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
const storedUser = localStorage.getItem("user");
return storedUser !== null ? JSON.parse(storedUser) : null;
});


// Side-effect to persist state changes to localStorage
useEffect(() => {
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
 }, [user]);

 const handleLogin = (userData) => setUser(userData);

 return (
 <div className="App">
 <BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
    {/*public Routes*/}
  <Route element={<AnonymousRoute isAuthenticated={!!user} />}>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login onLogin={handleLogin} />} />
    <Route path="/unauthorized" element={<Unauthorized />} />
    {/* ... other "anonymous" routes ... */}
  </Route>
    {/*we want to protect this Route*/}
  <Route element={<ProtectedRoute isAuthenticated={!!user} user={user} allowedRoles={["ADMINISTRATOR"]} />}>
    <Route
      path="/home"
      element={<Home user={user} setUser={setUser} />}
    />
    {/* ... other "authenticated" routes ... */}
  </Route>
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
</div>
);
}
export default App;
```

protectedRoute.js

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuthenticated },user) => {
const location = useLocation()
return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" state={{from:location}} replace />;
};

 const AnonymousRoute = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
 return isAuthenticated ? <Navigate to="/" replace /> : <Outlet 
 />;
 };

 export { ProtectedRoute, AnonymousRoute };
```

As of now I am trying to just Authenticate and show the page

now I need to add allowed roles and check this while Routing
if not need to send it to unauthorizedpage

Need some help

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73931932/8690857 Or is this like your last (*now deleted*) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75960921/8690857) where you need to conditionally redirect to different target paths?

Comment: Getting confused on Protected Route and  your above answer

Yes I deleted the post I guess it was not clear though I didn't get any answers

Comment: then what is the use of protected Route

Comment: Didn't get any answer? It was only 2 hours old! 

Comment: I thought i made mess and it was not understandable even though a lot of views were there I didn't find any answers so deleted

Comment: Route protection components are *abstractly* protecting a route based on a condition, or series of conditions. Your current `ProtectedRoute` uses a condition based on if a user is authenticated or not. My answer I links the component uses a condition based on a user with specific roles. You can mix anything you need to make the condition necessary for access to content you want to protect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253038/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-r9102).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is that you've managed to create a render loop redirecting between authenticated and anonymous routes.

For example:

- User accesses `"/"` will be get redirected to `"/home"`
- If they are authenticated but lack the correct role they get
  redirected to `"/unauthorized"`
- The `AnonymousRoute` sees they are authenticated and redirects back to `"/"`
- `"/"` redirects user to `"/home"`
- Repeat ad nauseam

This is the infinite loop.

You can create another route protection component that looks specifically at the user's roles and conditionally renders another `Outlet` or redirect to a ***safe*** route. A safe route is one that ***doesn't*** requires role check for the specific role(s) the current route is guarding for.

Example:

```
const RoleAccess = ({ roles = [], user, redirectTarget }) => {
  return !roles.length || roles.includes(user?.role)
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to={redirectTarget} replace />;
};
```

Example routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />

    {/*public Routes*/}
    <Route element={<AnonymousRoute isAuthenticated={!!user} />}>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login onLogin={handleLogin} />} />
      <Route path="/unauthorized" element={<Unauthorized />} />
      {/* ... other "anonymous" routes ... */}
    </Route>

    {/*we want to protect this Route*/}
    <Route element={<ProtectedRoute isAuthenticated={!!user} user={user} />}>
      <Route
        path="/home"
        element={<Home user={user} setUser={setUser} />}
      />
      <Route
        element={(
          <RoleAccess
            roles={["ADMINISTRATOR"]}
            redirectTarget="/home" // <-- safe authenticated, non-role-access route
            user={user}
          />
        )}
      >
        <Route
          path="/admin/*"
          element={<AdminDashboard />}
        />
        {/* ... other "admin" routes ... */}
      </Route>

      {/* ... other "authenticated" routes ... */}
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If you instead really want to redirect to `"/unauthorized"` then this route ***absolutely can not*** protect against authenticated users because they will simply be bounced back to `"/"` and then `"/home"` and not see they don't have access to the role access routes. `<Route path="/unauthorized" element={<Unauthorized />} />` would need to be moved out of the `AnonymousRoute` layout route in order for authenticated users to see it.