# react router dom and role based

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, roles

I'm struggling to implement dynamic role-based routing with the latest version of react-router-dom (v6.22.3). I have some ideas, but I'm finding it difficult to implement them fully.

Notes:

1. I familiar with examples described here [link][1]
2. Goal description :

   1. define roles in the router
   2. consume it in the outlet
3. The entire path are protected except login. so we dont need to add protected route (the app is function as protected) , just need to handle the role base

Here's what I've tried:

I've set up a mapping for my pages and defined roles for each page:

```
export const paths = {
  boo: { path: "/boo", roles: [] },
  foo: { path: "/foo", roles: ["admin", "manager"] },
};
```

And here's how I've set up my router: (defining the roles inside the id prop is the best option i found)

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      { path: paths.details.boo, element: <Boo/>, id: createRouteId("boo") },
      { path: paths.details.foo, element: <Foo/>, id: createRouteId("Foo") },
    ],
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
  },
]);

export default router;
```

Now, I'm wondering if there's any way to use a property other than "id" to uniquely identify routes. However, let's assume "id" is the best option.

In my App.tsx, I'm using a custom hook to get the user object, which looks like this:

```
{userName:string,roles:roles[],...}
```

I'm also attempting to check if the user has valid roles for the current route:

```
const isValidRole = (userRoles: string[], outletRole: string[]) => {
  return userRoles.some((role) => outletRole.includes(role));
};
```

Here's my App.tsx component: (here we use outlet and i try to consume the roles based on the location with the outlet)

```
function App() {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const getRouteIdFromOutlet = useOutlet();
  const [isValidRole] = useState(isRoleValid(user.roles, JSON.parse(getRouteIdFromOutlet.props.id)));

  if (!user) return <Login />;
  if(!isValidRole) throw new Error("Unauthorized"); // the error page will know what to render

  return (
    <Layout>
      <NavbarDesktop />
      <Content style={{ padding: "0 48px" }}>
        <Outlet />
      </Content>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

now the `const getRouteIdFromOutlet = useOutlet();` is the closest option i found in order to read the id from the route and utilize it here

Comment: Refer https://dev.to/bladearya/how-to-set-up-protected-how-to-protect-routes-for-different-user-roles-with-restricted-access-59j5

Comment: Does [How to create protected route with React-Router-DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289122/how-to-create-a-protected-route-with-react-router-dom) help answer your question?

Comment: @DrewReese it is not described the roles and how to dynamicly consume them at once. maybe i didnt explain well but i try to develop a clear way to define roles in routers and consume them in the outlet . its possible just with useOutlet but its not straight forward at all. i will edit the question to be more clear

Comment: @VishnuSKrish base on the link you provide and drawReese it seems i didnt describe well the question . i try to define the routes in the router and consme it in the outlet as i did with the id.

Comment: So you are not trying to create role-based protected route access? Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73931932/8690857?

Comment: @DrewReese i do but in different way , just thinking out of the box , its seems we can improve it . my code here can work and its seems it require less code to maintain , (just need to fix the usage of useOutlet)  . the other solution i found that defintly clear and works proabbly require more code , am i right?

Comment: The `useOutlet` is *basically* an internal implementation detail for the `Outlet` component. I *guess* you could use it like this, though it seems incredibly odd to encode access roles into the route id, but maybe that'll work for you. I'll take a closer look to see if I can understand your approach.

Comment: @DrewReese Tell me if there is anything I can do to assist you in understanding my mention. Basically, you are very right; it's a very odd way to encode access by using the useOutlet and id. I'm also pretty sure there is nothing out of the box. Maybe my approach is a suggestion, idea, or completely rubbish

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what/where you need specific help with. Is it in `App` trying to use `const [isValidRole] = useState(isRoleValid(user.roles, JSON.parse(getRouteIdFromOutlet.props.id)));`?

Comment: @DrewReese just replace the usage of role data transfered from id prop into other better prop ? and consume it in other way instead useOutlet (its very nested to get the id of spesific route)

Comment: Do you mean like in the linked answers we provided to you as examples that pass the access roles as props to the route protection component?

Comment: Nope - in the provided link we are not passing any data to the outlet except the rout data (path and element) and its implement the protected route which is similar a bit to what i implement here. but it cool be cleaner way if we pass the roles also with the route itself and we can consume it in the protected route parent (App in my case)

it will be better if i re edit the entire question ?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are saying is an issue or what isn't working as expected. From what I *can* understand it basically seems you are asking if there's a different `RouteObject` property you could use *other than* `id` for the use case you are trying to implement. If this is correct then the answer is "no", the `RouteObject` has the interface it has.

Comment: I think it's an interesting idea/concept. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that we could inspect live.

Comment: @DrewReese good idea , here a codesandbox example https://codesandbox.io/p/github/bennyh960/react_roles/main?workspaceId=d97d240b-1986-4191-b890-6c8d428acf8f

Comment: There is an issue loading the sandbox link. Did you ensure you saved all your latest changes in that sandbox? Is that sandbox marked to be publicly accessible?

Comment: Its seems public to me , i try to share the snippet , but dont know how do it on mobile

Comment: @DrewReese i added in the post body the markdown to the sandbox , please tell me if u can see.

Comment: The ErrorElement that you are expecting will only render when react-router's `loader` or `action` throws the error/response. You are throwing error from the App component which won't make that. Refer here 
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/error-element#errorelement

So writing protected route with including roles validation will be the better option

Comment: @VishnuSKrish the throwing response is get caught somehow by the router (the side effect is show also the uncaught runtime error)

Comment: Ok. Exactly what problem needs to be solved? We couldn't get it clearly from your question.

Comment: @VishnuSKrish it start with a problem and during the converstion it became  to new  approach to exam. try play with the sandbox and tell me if you can see this as a good practice . right now it working perfect and require much less code . (but the annoying thing is the runtime error)

Comment: I see, I had to strip off the query params of that first link, the sandbox appears to load now. ***Why*** are you throwing HTML `Response` objects from the UI code? By the time the code in your `useEffect` hooks is called to throw the error, the response from the server has already been handled by the client and the app is running. Are you wanting to use route loaders to check a user's authentication status and throw the `Response` there? It's still not clear what exactly you are trying to do here other than buck convention.

Comment: And like I said in your other post, the error appears to be a React overly to inform you your app crashed and happens in non-production builds.

Comment: @DrewReese if i will use loader to handle authentication i need to create/add loader for each path .
in this approach i just need to add id to the path . 

about the Response it was just to demonstrate  and let the error page to catugt it and identify it with 403 status

Comment: Well, FWIW the route loaders were intended to be used for fetching and loading actual data specific to the route, not authentication checks to see if a user can access the route. I guess this is irrelevant if you are not really intending to throw HTML Responses from the UI code though.

Comment: i think in terms od readability and maintanene it can be good aproach instead each path create is own loader (when most of the rols is handled from the ui)
but my experience is not like yours so now i less confident. tell me again please what wrong with this approach or at least how u can do it better

Comment: Like I said previously, I think the approach is interesting, and the only suggestion I have at the moment would be to redirect to your login route when a user needs to authenticate instead of rendering `Login` directly or throwing an error (*it's not an error to need authentication/role/etc to access*), e.g. something like `<Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: getRouteIdFromOutlet.props.path }} />`.

Comment: Thanks. Btw i replaced the throwing error with rendering the error page with some modifications.